# Using If Else statement to print a count

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

Im learning JS and Google apps script. Im just working on examples to help learn. Something Im sure is simple that Im stuck on. Is there a way to print out Dell and HP count using the same variable? I know I could add a second variable counter2 and use that but just looking understand preferred methods . I tried to comment out what I have tried. The sheet Im referencing has 100 Dell and 400 HP.

````
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var es = ss.getSheetByName("School1");
  var ms = ss.getSheetByName("School2");
  var hs = ss.getSheetByName("School3");
  var esValues = es.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counter = 0;
    //var esValues = es.getRange('A:C').getValues();
  Logger.log(esValues.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < esValues.length; i++){
     var data= esValues[i];
     var first = data[1];
     var last = data[0];
     var middle = data[2];
     var studentid = data[3];
     var device = data[4];
     if(device.includes("Dell")){
       counter++;
       //Logger.log(`Dell count is ${counter}`); //When add here it prints same line 100+ times  
       } else if(device.includes("HP")){
       counter++;
              }
     
  }
  Logger.log(`Dell count is ${counter}`)//Printing same count 500
  Logger.log(`Hp count is ${counter}`)//Printing same count 500
  
}```
````

Comment: You could turn counter into an Object: `counter.Dell++; counter.HP++` Or, if Dell and HP are the only options, track one, then subtract from the total to get the other.

Comment: I think you can use a simple reduce with an object for your task.

Comment: two countters is the simplest but you could do this `let [last, first, middle, studentid, device] = vs[i]`and same a lot space and replace for loop with forEach or map.

Answer (score 1):

So when logging the total of two different items using one variable isn't the way to do it. In your case both of your conditions will increase counter so while your for loop goes through it will always bump counter so it will hit 500 which is the total number of devices. Try something like this.

```
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var es = ss.getSheetByName("School1");
  var ms = ss.getSheetByName("School2");
  var hs = ss.getSheetByName("School3");
  var esValues = es.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counterDell = 0;
  var counterHP = 0; // New for just HP
    //var esValues = es.getRange('A:C').getValues();
  Logger.log(esValues.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < esValues.length; i++){
     var data= esValues[i];
     var first = data[1];
     var last = data[0];
     var middle = data[2];
     var studentid = data[3];
     var device = data[4];
     if(device.includes("Dell")){
       counterDell++;
       //Logger.log(`Dell count is ${counter}`); //When add here it prints same line 100+ times  
       } else if(device.includes("HP")){
       counterHP++;
              }
     
  }
  Logger.log(`Dell count is ${counterDell}`)//Printing same count 500
  Logger.log(`Hp count is ${counterHP}`)//Printing same count 500
  
}
```

Comment: Ok, I was on the right track then, One more question `Logger.log(esValues.length)` prints out 500.0 . If I wanted to drop the decimal I thought I could use Math.floor(). `Logger.log(typeof esValues.length` returns that its a number. However I cannot seem to figure out how to drop that decimal. I tried `Logger.log(Math.floor(esValues.length)`

Comment: So there are multiple ways to strip the decimal off the value. This link should be helpful. Whatever works best for you would be the one I go with https://www.jsdiaries.com/how-to-remove-decimal-places-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

When there are only `HP` and `Dells` in `device` field, it could be resolved.
But if there are more values can be used in `device` field, there is no solution rather than using two counters.

If only `HD` and `Dell`s are used, try this one.

````
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var es = ss.getSheetByName("School1");
  var ms = ss.getSheetByName("School2");
  var hs = ss.getSheetByName("School3");
  var esValues = es.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counter = 0;
    //var esValues = es.getRange('A:C').getValues();
  Logger.log(esValues.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < esValues.length; i++){
     var data= esValues[i];
     var first = data[1];
     var last = data[0];
     var middle = data[2];
     var studentid = data[3];
     var device = data[4];
     if(device.includes("Dell")){
       counter++;
     } 
  }
  Logger.log(`Dell count is ${counter}`)
  Logger.log(`Hp count is ${esValues.length - counter}`)
  
}```
````